# sending parameter from XAML to C# method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Very new to XAML/C# and I wanted to know how to send a parameter from XAML to a C# method.

This TextBlock `<TextBlock PreviewMouseDown="changeFont" />` would call a method with the signature
`changeFont(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)`

But I wanted to know if I could add a parameter to the signature like this:
`changeFont(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e, string Name)`

and send an argument via XAML
`<TextBlock PreviewMouseDown="changeFont('Bob')" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in WPF; that's not how it's designed. If you need additional information to process the `PreviewMouseDown` event, you'll have to get it from somewhere else.

`sender` gives you the element that raised the event (in your case the `TextBlock`). So one option is to use the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag) property:

```
<TextBlock PreviewMouseDown="changeFont" Tag="Bob"/>
```

```
changeFont(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var moreInfo = ((TextBlock)sender).Tag;

    ...
}
```

---

One other thing to look into is the use of [`commands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand). Commands let you add a `CommandParameter`. Certain controls `Command` property that can be set to execute said command when they are interacted with, like when a `Button` is clicked. This isn't the case for `TextBlock`, but it might be useful later on.

Comment: i like this , thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The XAML snippet `PreviewMouseDown="changeFont"` attaches an event handler to the `PreviewMouseDown` event. And the event handler `changeFont` needs to have a fixed signature. You cannot simply add a parameter.

That being said, `changeFont` does not sound like the name of an event handler anyway. It is an action. If you have multiple of these text blocks and you want to re-use the `changeFont` method, you could define separate event handlers that each call the action:

```
<TextBlock PreviewMouseDown="BobPreviewMouseDown" />
<TextBlock PreviewMouseDown="AlicePreviewMouseDown" />
```

```
void BobPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    changeFont("Bob");
}

void AlicePreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    changeFont("Alice")
}
```

That's one option. Of course, there are many others. You could, e.g., also have a single event handler and derive the parameter from the `sender` object (e.g. with an attached property or similar).

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid writing a handful of methods that more-or-less do the same thing, but your comment on attached properties is leading me in the right direction - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Command and CommandParameter properties. It's better to use MVVM pattern and link to a command from your ViewModel, but if you don't use it, you also can use the Routed Command system and set an event handler for the command via `CommandBinding` property:

```
<Button Content="Bob button"
        Command="{Binding ChangeFont}"
        CommandParameter="Bob" />
```

I used `<Button />` here, but if you want it to look like a `<TextBlock />` you can change its appearance by changing it's `Template` property. But remember, that user expects that a button behaves like a button while a text block behaves like a text block.